# Rubymotion multilevel BW::HTTP calls return early

Tags: rubymotion

I am attempting to call a method, from_server, giving it a block that will accept the results. from_server loads a list of items from an api then for each in the list calls a function add_update giving it a block to accept the results for each detail. When all of the details have been handled, the from_server calls its block to return the summary.

I can get the low levels to work ok. My problem is the first function calls its block before everything is done.

Not sure why or where I need to put the block.call

The main caller

```rb
from_server do |updates, inserts|
  puts "\n  Updates = #{updates}"
  puts "  Inserts = #{inserts}\n\n"
  puts 'all Done'
end
```

the from_server function that calles the

```rb
def from_server(&block)
  inserts = 0
  updates = 0
  channels = [1,2,4,6,7]
  for channels.each do
    add_update("/api/channels/#{channel}", &block) do |added, channel|
      if added
        inserts += 1
      else
        updates += 1
      end
      #do some things with channel
    end
    block.call(updates, inserts) unless block.nil? # problem is here gets returned as soon as all channels have been started on a thread
  end
end
```

gets the list and processes each item

```rb
def from_server(&block)
  uri = '/api/channels'
  ApiRequest.get(uri) do |header, body|
    new_count = 0
    update_count = 0
    puts "\nList Body = #{body}\n"
    body.each do |channel|
      add_update(channel['uri']) do |new, ad_channel|
        if new
          puts "\nNew #{ad_channel}"
          new_count += 1
        else
          puts "\nUpdate #{ad_channel}"
          update_count += 1
        end
        puts
      end
    end
    puts "\nDONE\n"
    block.call(update_count, new_count) unless block.nil?
    puts "All Requests Done\n"
  end
  puts "Request all channels started"
end
```

Processes each item

```rb
def add_update(channel_uri, &block)
  ApiRequest.get(channel_uri) do |header, body|
    if ad_channel = AdvChannel.find(name: body['name']).first
      puts "\n#{ad_channel.name} already exists"
      new = false
    else
      ad_channel = AdvChannel.create(name: body['name'],
                                     phone: body['phone'],
                                     url: body['uri'],
                                     admin_url: body['admin_url'],
                                     channel_code: body['channel_code'],
                                     uri: channel_uri)
      puts "\nInserting #{ad_channel.name} - #{ad_channel.id}"
      new = true
    end
    block.call(new, ad_channel)  if block_given?
  end
```

The results from executing the caller are:
give me the following:

```
Request all channels started immediately  (expected)
the List Body string (expected)
Add update one started (expected)

DONE  (unexpected should be after all are done)
  Updates = 0  (unexpected should be after all are done)
  Inserts = 0   (unexpected should be after all are done)
all Done   (unexpected should be after all are done)
All Requested Done (unexpected should be after all are done)

the insert or update information for each channel (expected)
```

How do I get the summary after all is complete?

Comment: Can you reformat your question? The code blocks are all messed up.

Comment: Sorry corrected the functions. from_server add or updates all the channels from the server to the local database and does some work with each one is the flow.